A subfield $R \subseteq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$ with 'many' generators $w$, $R(w)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$
Let $R \subseteq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$ and assume that $R=\mathbb{C}(u,v)$, where $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$.
Here $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$.

Assume that $R$ satisfies the following 'rare' property:
For every monomial $x^iy^j$, $i \in \mathbb{N}$, $j \in \mathbb{N}$ (except the case $i=j=0$, for which we assume nothing), we have $\mathbb{C}(u,v,x^iy^j)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

Question: Is it true that $R=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$?
I am not able to find a counterexample, but perhaps there is such.
I do not mind to further assume that $x+y$ also satisfies $\mathbb{C}(u,v,x+y)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
Any help is welcome! Thank you very much.

Edit: Please, what about the following version of the above question:
Same as the above question, except that now the property does not include the diagonal, namely, $\mathbb{C}(u,v,x^ny^n)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, $n \geq 1$, may not hold.
I am not sure which of the following three options is better to assume for every $n \geq 1$:

There is no information about adding $x^ny^n$ to $\mathbb{C}(u,v)$.
$\mathbb{C}(u,v,x^ny^n) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
$x^ny^n \in \mathbb{C}(u,v)$.

Perhaps the third option, $x^ny^n \in \mathbb{C}(u,v)$, has the following solution, based on the answer to the original question:
For a given field $F$ and a given pair $(i,j) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, denote by $C_{F,i,j}$ the condition/property that $F(x^iy^j)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, in other words, the condition that $x^iy^j$ is a primitive element for the extension $F \subseteq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
Then the answer shows the following: If $C_{R,i,j}$ holds for every $(i,j) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} - (0,0)$,
then $[\mathbb{C}(x,y) : R]=2$.
(Trivially, if $C_{R,0,0}$ holds, then $R=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, so in this case $[\mathbb{C}(x,y) : R ]=1$).
Now take $\tilde{R}=\mathbb{C}(\tilde{u},\tilde{v})$, where $\tilde{u}, \tilde{v} \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$, and assume that $C_{\tilde{R},i,j}$ holds for every $(i,j) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} - D$,
where $D= \{(n,n)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.
Moreover, assume that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $x^ny^n \in \tilde{R}$.
Claim: $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):\tilde{R}]\leq 2$.
Proof of claim: Same as the answer, except that the last two lines are changed, the map is not surjective, $\tilde{R} \subseteq \mathbb{C}(x,y) \subseteq L$. Therefore, by considerations of degree extensions,
$[\mathbb{C}(x,y):\tilde{R}]\leq 2$.
Maybe I am missing something.
Should I ask this as a new question, or is it ok to ask it here?

$S:=\mathbb{C}(xy,x+y)$, the field of symmetric functions w.r.t. the exchange involution $(x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$, is not an example for $R$, since $S(x^ny^n)=\mathbb{C}(xy,x+y,x^ny^n)=S \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$. However, $S$ is an example for $\tilde{R}$.

Start with $R=\mathbb{C}(u,v)$ and consider its quadratic extension $L=R(\sqrt{u})=R(s)=\mathbb{C}(s,v)$ with $s^2=u$.
Take an element $z$ of $L$, viewed as a rational function $z(s,v)$. Then $R(z)=L$ iff $z\notin R$ (because $[L:R]=2$) iff $\sigma(z)\neq z$ where $\sigma(z)$ is the $\mathrm{Gal}(L/R)$-conjugate of $z$ which is $z(-s,v)$.
We can also view $L$ as $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ in many different ways; let us pick
$$x=s+v, \quad y=s+2v.$$
For $i, j\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $x^i y^j=
(s+v)^i (s+2v)^j$ and $\sigma(x^i y^j)=
(-s+v)^i (-s+2v)^j$. If $(i,j)\neq(0,0)$ these are always different, so $x^i y^j\notin R$ and thus $R(x^i y^j)=L$.

Thank you very much!! Please, if I understand your answer, you proved that for a given $R$ satisfying the condition of my question, we have $[\mathbb{C}(x,y) : R]=2$?

$s$ is a root of $T^2-u \in \mathbb{C}(u,v)[T]$, so $s$ belongs to an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{C}(u,v)$. Perhaps now we divide into two cases: (1) $s \in \mathbb{C}(x,y)$. (2) $s \in \overline{\mathbb{C}(x,y)} - \mathbb{C}(x,y)$. In case (1) $L=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ and $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):R]=2$. In case (2) perhaps $R=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

First comment: yes, but I would not be surprised if your "rare" property were not rare at all.

I don't understand the second comment.

Please, I do not understand why we can view $L$ as $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$. I just see that $L \subset \overline{\mathbb{C}(u,v)}$, a subfield of an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{C}(u,v)$. An explanation would help. Thank you!

Well, $(x,y)$ as defined is algebraically free and generates $L$ over $\mathbb{C}$, whence an isomorphism $\mathbb{C(x,y)\cong L$.

I think the last bit of the preceding comment of @Laurent is supposed to be $\mathbb{C}(x,y)\cong L$.

@GerryMyerson, thanks. Truly, it is clear that $L$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, because $L=\mathbb{C}(s,v)$ with $s,v$ algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$. I do not understand why the choice $x=s+v, y=s+2v$ is possible; it implies that $v=y-x$, which may not hold. So even if this was just an example, how we guarantee that there is a valid choice?

Also, for example, $[\mathbb{C}(t^{\frac{1}{2}}):\mathbb{C}(t)]=2$, $[\mathbb{C}(t^{\frac{1}{3}}):\mathbb{C}(t)]=3$, with $\mathbb{C}(t^{\frac{1}{2}}) \simeq \mathbb{C}(t^{\frac{1}{3}})$, so isomorphic fields may not have equal dimension over same subfield. But perhaps this is not a problem here, with the map $s \mapsto -s$ combined with the 'rare' property.

@LaurentMoret-Bailly, please, do you allow me to quote this post mentioning your name in the acknowledgements of a paper I'm willing to send to arXiv? Is it ok? Thank you.

@user237522 No problem!

@LaurentMoret-Bailly, thank you very much! Great! I hope to upload it to arXiv in a few hours, so hopefully it will appear in 30 hours.
