Finding $\mathbb{C}(u,v)$ such that $\mathbb{C}(u,v,x^p+y^p)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, for every prime number $p$
Denote the set of prime numbers by $P$, $P=\{2,3,5,7,\ldots\}$.
Let $F \subseteq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$ be a subfield of $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, and for $w \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ denote by $F(w)$ the subfield of $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ generated by $F$ and $w$.
Assume that $F$ satisfies the following three properties:
(p1) $F=\mathbb{C}(u,v)$ with $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$.
(p2) For every $p \in P$, $F(x^p+y^p)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
(p3) $F(x+y)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

Question: Is it true that for such $F$ necessarily $x \in F$ or $y \in F$? If not, is there something interesting that can be said about $F$?

For example: Take $F=\mathbb{C}(xf,y)$, where $f \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ and $\gcd(f,x)=1$. $F$ satisfies the three properties; indeed, for every $n \in \{1\} \cup P$, $F(x^n+y^n)=\mathbb{C}(xf,y,x^n+y^n)=\mathbb{C}(xf,y,x^n)$. By the result presented here, $\mathbb{C}(xf,x^n)=\mathbb{C}(x)$ (because $\langle xf,x^n \rangle = \langle x \rangle$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x]$, by our choice of $f$), so $F(x^n+y^n)=\mathbb{C}(xf,x^n,y)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

But maybe there are examples of $F$ such that $x \notin F$ and $y \notin F$?

Remarks:

An 'opposite' question is this question, in which $x^n+y^n$ is already in the subfield, for some fixed $n$, not a generator. Here $x^n+y^n$ are generators for prime numbers $n$ or $n=1$.

Also asked here without comments.


Thank you very much!

If we change the second property to: For every $p \in P$, $F(x^p+ay^p)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, for some $a \in \mathbb{C}$ (fixed for all $p \in P$), then the question has a negative answer. Symmetric functions is a counterexample.

Not much can be said about $F$. The second conditions should hold for $\mathbb C(u,v)$ for $u$ and $v$ two "generic" algebraically independent polynomials.
For an explicit construction, take $u=(x-1)^2$ and $v= (y-1)^2$. Then $F=\mathbb C(u,v)$ is the fixed field of the group of automorphisms generated by $(x,y )\mapsto (2-x, y)$ and $(x,y)\mapsto (x,2-y)$. By Galois theory $F(t)=\mathbb C(x,y)$ if and only if $t$ is not fixed by any nontrivial automorphism in this group. By plugging in, we see that $x^n+y^n$ is not fixed by any nontrivial automorphism in this group for any $n>0$, so indeed these all generate $\mathbb C(x,y)$.

Thank you! (I have written a comment, with a slight change of the second property, finding a counterexample, not for my original question, but to the new version presented in my comment).

Truly, I thought about the above question when thinking about another question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/472877/a-subfield-r-subseteq-mathbbcx-y-with-many-generators-w-rw-math I will explain later what is the connection between the two questions.

The connection between the two questions: In the former, linked question, I have asked if $R=\mathbb{C}(u,v)$ with $u,v$ algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$, such that $C_{i,j}$ holds for every $(i,j) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} - (0,0)$, then $R=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$? The answer: $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):R]=2$. (Actually. I have asked also about an additional condition $R(x+y)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, so maybe with this additional condition we have $R=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$). Where $C_{i,j}$ says: $R(x^iy^j)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, namely, $x^iy^j$ is a primitive element for the extension.

@user237522 The idea behind answering both questions is the same: Take $R$ to be the fixed points of a group action on $\mathbb C(x,y)$, and just check no nontrivial element of the group fixes the additional elements you are adding (e.g. $x^i y^j$ in that case).

Thank you, nice observation! Please, if we combine the edit of the linked question + the above question to the following: Given $R=\mathbb{C}(u,v)$ as usual, such that (1) $C_{i,j}$ holds for every $(i,j) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} - D$, $D={(n,n)}{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, (2) $E{p,p}$ holds for every $p \in P \cup {1}$, (3) $xy \in R$. Where $C_{i,j}$ says $R(x^iy^j)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ and $E_{i,j}$ says $R(x^i+y^j)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$. Remark: (3) is to guarantee that $x^ny^n \in R$, so $C_{n,n}$ is not assumed anymore (to exclude $R=R(x^my^m)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, if $xy \in R$).

@user237522 This is not a question.

Oh, you are right.. The question is: If the three conditions (1),(2),(3) hold, is it true that $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):R] \leq 2$?

@user237522 No, for example $R = \mathbb C( (x-1)^3, xy)$.

Wow, very nice! I will have to think why conditions (1) and (2) hold in your counterexample. So the answer to the linked question (the original question, not the edit) is the best we can say? the original question with $C_{i,j}$, $(i,j) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} - (0,0)$.

Please, is the answer in the link has no gaps or errors? I am slightly confused about it. Thank you very much! https://mathoverflow.net/questions/472877/a-subfield-r-subseteq-mathbbcx-y-with-many-generators-w-rw-math Perhaps it is ok, since all monomials $x^iy^j$ (except $i=j=0$) are primitive elements for the extension. But in $\mathbb{C}(t)$ we can take $h(t)=t^m-t^{m-1}$ for arbitrary $m \geq 1$, obtain that each of ${t^n}_{t \geq 1}$ is a primitive element for the extension, $\mathbb{C}(t^m-t^{m-1})(t^n)=\mathbb{C}(t)$, but $[\mathbb{C}(t):\mathbb{C}(t^m-t^{m-1})]=m$.

The one-dimensional case does not contradict the result in the link. I just thought it is relevant to check what happens in that case. If we adjust it to the two-dimensional case, it would not be a counterexample: $u=x^m-x^{m-1}$, $v=y$. But $R=\mathbb{C}(x^m-x^{m-1},y)$ does not satisfy all the $C_{i,j}$'s, for example, $R(y^l) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$, for every $l \geq 1$.
