$F=\mathbb{C}(u,v)$ satisfying: For every $a,b \in \mathbb{C}[y],c,d \in \mathbb{C}[x]$: $\mathbb{C}(x,y)=F(ax+b)=F(cy+d)$
Let $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, where $u$ and $v$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$ and $F=\mathbb{C}(u,v)$. Of course, $d:=[\mathbb{C}(x,y):F] < \infty$.
Denote the following condition $P_{a,b}$: $\mathbb{C}(u,v)(ax+b)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$,
where $a,b \in \mathbb{C}[y]$.
Denote the following condition $Q_{c,d}$: $\mathbb{C}(u,v)(cy+d)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$,
where $c,d \in \mathbb{C}[x]$.
Assume that:

For every $a,b \in \mathbb{C}[y]$, $P_{a,b}$ holds.
For every $c,d \in \mathbb{C}[x]$, $Q_{c,d}$ holds.

Question: Is it true that $F=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$? Or $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):F] \leq 2$? Or is there something else that can be said about $u$, $v$ or $d$?
I suspect that $F=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, but not sure how to prove this. However, I may be wrong.
Attempts for counterexamples:
(1) $u=x^2, v=xy$: For example, $P_{y,0}$ does not hold and $Q_{x,0}$ does not hold (other conditions do not hold).
(2) $u=x+y, v=x^2+y^2$: $F=S_{\alpha}$ the field of symmetric functions w.r.t. the exchange involution $\alpha: (x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$. For example, $P_{y,0}$ does not hold and $Q_{x,0}$ does not hold, since $\mathbb{C}(x+y,x^2+y^2)(xy)=S_{\alpha} \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
(3) $u=x^3+y, v=y^3+x$: $P_{1,y^3}, Q_{1,x^3}$ do not hold.
(4) $u=x^2y^2, v=x^5y^3$: For $Q_{0,x^8}$, $F(x^8)=F \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$. (Maybe I have an error).
Thank you very much!

Concerning the nice counterexamples in the related questions, they are not counterexamples here since: (1) $u=xy, v=x+y$: $P_{1,y}, Q_{1,x}, P_{y,0}, Q_{x,0}$ do not hold. (2) $u=x+xy, v=x^2y$: $Q_{x,x}, Q_{x^2,0}$ do not hold. (4) $u=(x-1)^2, v=(y-1)^2$: $P_{0,(y-1)^2}, Q_{0,(x-1)^2}$ do not hold.

$u=x^2+y^2, v=x^3+y^3$? I do not think it is a counterexample.

The one who downvoted, if there is an easy counterexample please let me know.

An attempt of proof: We assume that $F=\mathbb{C}(u,v) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$ and try to show that this is impossible. Clearly, all the primitive elements $ax+b, cy+d$ are not in $F$ (since if they were in $F$, then $F=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$). Now I am trying to apply https://mathoverflow.net/questions/472877/a-subfield-r-subseteq-mathbbcx-y-with-many-generators-w-rw-math?rq=1 but I do not have all the conditions appearing there in order to conclude that $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):F]=2$.

I suppose you would want to exclude the following two cases:

$a = 0$ and $b \in \mathbb{C}$;
$c = 0$ and $d \in \mathbb{C}$.

Edit: In any event, if I understand your question correctly, then I think the answer is negative: $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):F]$ can be bigger than $2$.
Below I provide an example of $F$ such that $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):F] = 2$. However, I believe a similar principle can be used to construct $F$ such that $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):F]$ is an arbitrary prime number $p$: take $(u,v) := (x', y'^p)$ where
$$(x',y') := (x+y^q + (y+x+y^q)^q, y+x+y^q)$$
such that $q$ is coprime to $p$, and then show that any automorphism of $\mathbb{C}[x',y']$ that maps $(x',y') \mapsto (x', \zeta y')$ where $\zeta$ is a nontrivial $p$-th root of $1$ does not fix $P_{a,b}$ or $Q_{c,d}$ under the assumptions specified in the beginning.
Construction of $F$ with $[\mathbb{C}(x,y): F] = 2$. Note that there is a case at the end that I did not check - please check it.
We will use the trick from the answer to another question of yours, but first use generators of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ which are nonlinear in $x,y$: take $(x',y') := (x+y^2 + (y+x+y^2)^2, y+x+y^2)$. Then $\mathbb{C}[x,y] = \mathbb{C}[x',y']$ since the map $(x,y) \mapsto (x',y')$ is a composition of automorphisms:
$$(x,y) \mapsto (x+y^2, y) \mapsto (x+y^2, y+x+y^2) \mapsto (x+y^2 + (y+x+y^2)^2, y+x+y^2)$$
Then consider $(u,v) := (x'+y', x'y')$.
Claim. $\mathbb{C}(u,v,f) = \mathbb{C}(x,y)$, where $f$ is either $P_{a,b}$ or $Q_{c,d}$, and the two cases specified above are excluded.
Proof. Since $[\mathbb{C}(x,y): \mathbb{C}(u,v)] = 2$, it suffices to show that $f \not\in \mathbb{C}(u,v)$, and for that, it suffices to show that the automorphism $\sigma$ of $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ that maps $(x',y') \mapsto (y',x')$ does not fix $f$. Note that
$$(x,y) = (x'-y'^2 - (y'- x'+ y'^2)^2, y'- x'+ y'^2)$$
We will show that $\deg_{x'}(f) \neq \deg_{y'}(f)$ (which would be sufficient to prove the claim). First consider the case that $f = P_{a,b} = a(y)x + b(y)$. If $a = 0$ and $b$ is a non-constant polynomial, then it is clear that
$$\deg_{y'}(f) = 2\deg(b) > \deg(b) = \deg_{x'}(f)$$
So assume $a(y) \neq 0$. Then
$$f = a(y'- x'+ y'^2)(x'-y'^2) + c(y'-x'+y'^2)$$
where $c(y) := a(y)y^2 + b(y)$. Let $d := \deg(a)$, and $e := \deg(c)$. If $e \neq d+1$, then there is no cancellation of the term with the highest degree in $y'$, and
$$\deg_{y'}(f) = \max\{2(d+1), 2e\} > \max\{d+1, e\} \geq \deg_{x'}(f)$$
The only way there is a cancellation is if $e = d+1$, and the leading coefficients of $a$ and $c$ are equal, so that
$$f = \mu(y'- x'+ y'^2)^d(x'-y'^2) + \mu(y'-x'+y'^2)^{d+1} + a'(y'- x'+ y'^2)(x'-y'^2) + c'(y'-x'+y'^2)$$
for some $\mu \neq 0 \in \mathbb{C}$, and $a',c' \in \mathbb{C}(y)$ with $\deg(a') \leq d-1$ and $\deg(c') \leq d$. Then the coefficient of $y'^{2d+1}$ in $f$ is $\mu \neq 0$, so that
$$\deg_{y'}(f) = 2d+1 > \deg_{x'}(f)$$
unless $d = 0$. However, the $d = 0$ case is easier to resolve. This completes the proof for the case of $P_{a,b}$. I believe the $Q_{c,d}$ case is similar - but do check it.

Thank you very much! I really apologize for not being clear, but I allowed $a=0$ or $c=0$. Your answer is still interesting.

Perhaps it follows that $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):F] \leq 2$? (However, the answer to the previous question does not hold here).

Actually the assumption $a \neq 0$ or $c \neq 0$ is unnecessary: I was a bit confused. Will update the answer accordingly.

Thank you for the clarification.

Please, do you think that necessarily $d=[\mathbb{C}(x,y):F] \leq 2$, or it was just  easier to build a counterexample with $d=2$, but it is possible to build counterexamples with $d \geq 3$?

"I suppose you would want to exclude the following two cases:

$a = 0$ and $b \in \mathbb{C}$;
$c = 0$ and $d \in \mathbb{C}$." Yes, this is correct. Thanks.


Check the new edit regarding the broader question.

Thank you, yes I see now your edit with $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):F]=p$. Nice.

So probably the only question of mine in this series of questions which has a positive answer is https://mathoverflow.net/questions/472877/a-subfield-r-subseteq-mathbbcx-y-with-many-generators-w-rw-math?noredirect=1&lq=1 since all the generators $x^iy^j$ were considered.
